# How to initialise existing Gnosis SAFE and create transaction?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk

I have a node.js file where I want to initialise an existing Gnosis SAFE where my address is a signer and create transactions with it.

I'm on the SDK version 1.3.0 and this is my code -->

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const { SafeFactory, EthersAdapter } = require("@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk");

const provider = new ethers.providers.getDefaultProvider("rinkeby");
const owner1 = new ethers.Wallet(
process.env.PRIV_KEY,  provider
);

async function test() {
  const safeSdk = await SafeFactory.create({
    ethAdapter: new EthersAdapter({
      ethers,
      signer: owner1,
    }),
    safeAddress: process.env.SAFE_ADDRESS,
  });
  const transaction = {
    to: process.env.RECEIVER_ADDRESS,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0001"),
    data: "0x537461636b45786368616e6765",
  };
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction);
  const executeTxResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);
  await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse?.wait();
}
test();
```

This is what I get as output -->

```
/home/runner/JuniorSlateblueHexadecimal/index.js:23
  const safeTransaction = await safeSdk.createTransaction(transaction);
                                        ^

TypeError: safeSdk.createTransaction is not a function
    at test (/home/runner/JuniorSlateblueHexadecimal/index.js:23:41)
```

What is the solution? Tried using the Safe object instead of SafeFactory too but still doesn't work. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `safeSdk` is an instance of the `SafeProxyFactory`, not an instance of the `SafeProxy`. You need to call the method `deploySafe` from the factory instance. The object returned will be the `safeSdk`.

Here are the steps on how to deploy a new Safe from the `ProxyFactory`: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#2-deploy-a-new-safe

To instantiate the Safe Core SDK with an already deployed Safe, you can call the method `create` from the `Safe` class: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-core-sdk/tree/main/packages/safe-core-sdk#create-1